# Android Studio Navigation bar showing Apps's name is missing?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, toolbar, android-titlebar

When I launch the apps in Emulator, I realize the Navigation bar which shows apps name is missing. May I know what's going on?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText first_name;
EditText last_name;
Button button_submit;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    first_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_name);
    last_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last_name);
    button_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_submit);
    button_submit.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("first_name", first_name.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("last_name", last_name.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.yuqk.intent_usage">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ViewActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

**Style.xml**

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Please refer the the screenshot for reference.. Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: have you add `toolbar` on xml and java code ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. If so, you need to change it to

```
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

(assuming you have AppTheme defined in `styles.xml` with parent `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` or similar).

Comment: android:theme="@style/AppTheme"   It's default, i didn't change anything.

Comment: Please show your `AndroidManifest.xml` and `styles.xml` then.

Comment: You may also try these two ideas:
1. add `ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); ab.show();` to your `onCreate()` method.
2. try making your activity extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`.
    ...

Answer (score 2):

Check this if you add `toolbar` in xml file like this

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

then add this code to your `MainActivity.java` file.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and in **Manifest.xml** you have use this theme.

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

**styles.xml** you have this

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: android:theme="@style/AppTheme"   It's default theme, i didn't change anything. I just created an project and run it. How come i need to change so many things in order to show the toolbar?

Comment: @gosulove you have to go through this pattern .. because if you have set `NoActionBar` theme then `ActionBar` is disable and you can add `Toolabr` to that place and other two thing I mention is how to show the `Toolbar`.

Comment: No, i didn't set "NoActionBar " . Its default android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

Comment: @gosulove one last thing add your `Activity` xml I will change all that thing and tell you just put the xml..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117302/discussion-between-gosulove-and-ironman).

Answer (score 1):

If you have `toolbar` included in your xml, add this line of code inside of `onCreate()` method, right after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: It's default theme, i didn't change anything. I just created an project and run it. How come i need to change so many things in order to show the toolbar?

Comment: Your problem seems to be more than this. But these line of code are also default and mandatory. If I delete these lines in working app, I will still be able to see my toolbar BUT it will be empty. Write these lines and see changes

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in the Layout editor named 'Show layout decorations' 
You must have this option turned off. 
There is a button with the image of an eye above the mobile screen in android studio. Click on that and a drop down menu should be seen. Check the 'Show Layout Decorations' and your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

It might that you have changed **Style.xml** file with theme style of *NoActionBar*

please change it to 
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

and then Run